# Jquery for retaining the selected value in select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am playing some show/hide function using my select drop down. Here is the html for select,

```
<select id="sel1" size="1" name="">
    <option selected="selected" value="0">Select Here</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
</select>
```

Here is my jquery,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sel1").change(fun);  
});


function fun(){  
   var selected = $("#sel1 option:selected");       

   if(selected.val() == 1) {  
      $("#div1").slideDown("slow");
      $('#div2').slideUp("slow");
   } else if(selected.val() == 2) {
      $("#div1").slideUp("slow");
      $('#div2').slideDown("slow");
   } else {
      $("#div1").slideUp("slow");
      $('#div2').slideUp("slow");
   }
};
```

But after the value sent to the server and return back, I want to retain the div1 or div2 based on the value select in the dropdown. But as of now, both the div are not displaying because of display=none at initial level. Any way to retain this?

Comment: Just a remark: For a "non-multiple" select you can get the currently selected value with `$('#sel1').val()`. There's no need to refer to `option:selected`

Comment: are you submitting the form via ajax?

Comment: HIya bruv please provide more html or might be a jsfiddle you might get more responces, have a nice one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your HTML is generated using a server-side language, your best option would be to only add the `display: none` CSS property to them when appropriate. Alternatively, you could just trigger the `change` event handler when the DOM is ready, using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sel1").change(fun).trigger('change');  
});
```